# Pushing Notification even when the app is closed in android

Tags: android, notifications

I am pushing the notification from my app and refreshing the notification method every one minute. The notification is displayed when the app is open. How to push the notification even the app is closed?

```
public void CustomNotification(String title_notify,String image_notify) {
    // Using RemoteViews to bind custom layouts into Notification
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),
            R.layout.customnotification);

    // Set Notification Title
    String strtitle = title_notify;
    // Set Notification Text
    String strtext = "";

    // Open NotificationView Class on Notification Click
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Notification_ListView.class);
    // Send data to NotificationView Class
    intent.putExtra("title", strtitle);

    intent.putExtra("location", location);
    intent.putExtra("text", strtext);
    intent.putExtra("user_id", user_id);
    intent.putExtra("country_id", country_id);
    // Open NotificationView.java Activity
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    bitmap = getBitmapFromURL(image_notify);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            // Set Icon
            .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
            // Set Ticker Message  
            .setTicker("")
            // Dismiss Notification
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            // Set PendingIntent into Notification
            .setContentIntent(pIntent)
            // Set RemoteViews into Notification
            .setContent(remoteViews);

    // Locate and set the Image into customnotificationtext.xml ImageViews
    remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imagenotileft,bitmap);
    //remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imagenotiright,R.drawable.androidhappy);

    // Locate and set the Text into customnotificationtext.xml TextViews
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title,strtitle);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text,strtext);

    Random random = new Random();
    int m = random.nextInt(9999 - 1000) + 1000;
    // Create Notification Manager
    NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Build Notification with Notification Manager
    notificationmanager.notify(m, builder.build());

}
```

Comment: Used `Service` for that...

Comment: Could you please let me know a brief of how to use service to get what I want?

Comment: You might want to use a Service with an AlarmManager to acheive this purpose

Comment: Search on _Google_ for that..

Comment: Android docs helps a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Example [push notification](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Comment: I don't want GCM to be used. Is there any other way without GCM?

Comment: Use Service instead of GCM

Comment: I tried with service. It works when the app is opened and running in background. But doesnt work when the app is removed from recently used app tray